# setup.bash permission denied

Tags: ros, permission, ros-indigo, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Urgent Help, Hello Everyone,

So i am new to ROS environment,

I started working on an already built ROS environment for a robot

So whe i type

```
 /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

i get a reply

```
permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340820/setup.bash-permission-denied/) by [Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50582/yadav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
Could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered? Thanks.

**Comment by [Yadav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50582/yadav/) on 2020-03-10**:
:P oops Sorry , Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So whe i type
>
> ```
>  /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
> ```

is that a verbatim copy-paste of the command you're trying to use?

If so: that's not the correct command. You'll want to use `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` or `. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` (note the first dot there).

Also note: Indigo is EOL. Ubuntu Trusty is also EOL.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3